# Which naming Convention Better represent MongoDB Collection ?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, naming-conventions

I have Mongo DB Collection Call "DataBox"

```
{ 
   name : { type : String },
   typeOfDataBox : { type : String }  // <---- 01
   type : { type : String }  // <---- 02
   << any Suggestion >> : { type : String }  // <---- 03
}
```

Above I mention 01, 02, 03 
Using Popper naming Convention.
Any one Can help me Suggestion for Represent Type of DataBox ?

If not clear pls comment.

Thanks

Comment: how do you define "DataBox" ?

Comment: hi, #Fahadsk. DataBox is just DB Collection. I wanted to Define type of DataBox Variable Properly.  Type of DataBox Can can be "Personal, Team, Custom, etc ..."

Comment: If your "DataBox" collection represents different categories then you can define it as "dataBoxCategory"  or "dataBoxSection" or may be "division"